# How to Parse JSON and use axios without express

Tags: json, node.js, twitter, reddit

I'm currently making a twitter bot with node.js and I don't want to make a server with express unless I have to.

```js
// imports

var Twit=require('twit');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// config.js has my authentication
var config = require('./config');
var axios = require('axios');


axios.get('https://api.reddit.com/r/worldnews/hot.json?', { params: { sort: 'hot', limit: 1 } })
.then(response => {
  var redditdata= response.data;
  console.log(redditdata);
  console.log(response.status);
})

var T = new Twit(config);

T.post('statuses/update', { status: redditdata.data.children.data.title + " " + redditdata.data.children.data.url }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

How do I input the reddit title and the url in the twitter post request? I know how to do this if with express server but how do I without a express?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable and then assign "redditdata.data.children.data" to that global variable inside your axios function. then you can access the data you want from a global variable. Right now, you are trying to get "redditdata.data.children.data" inside another function and it does not work because of function scope.

Comment: The issue is that axios.get is not running. In the past I always used axios with express. How do I make it work without express?